# Reusable make file for any single source c file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to do the following with make:

```
$ make app1 // takes app1.c, compiles it to app1.elf
$ make app2 // takes app2.c, compiles it to app2.elf
```

The next step that I'd want to accomplish is specify the prefix of source and header files.

```
$ make app1
```

Should take all source and header files prefixed with app1-* (app1-src1.c, app1-src2.c, etc., app1-src1.h, app1-src2.h, etc.) and compile it into app1.elf

What I have so far isn't working to well for me. It can only generate only the specified prefix but no .elf at the end using the prefix for the input source file:

```
all: %

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c %.c

%: %.o
    gcc %.o -o %.elf
```

Using 'make abc' successfully takes abc.c and compiles it into abc instead of what I want abc.elf.

Can I get some help on this please?

Comment: Doesn't `make` have some crazy defaults that basically already subsume the first step of your question? Just `make x` works if you have a file called `x.c` or `x.cpp`, with no `Makefile` in sight. It respects `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` and their like, too.

Comment: How would you do it without Make, if you knew what source and header files existed? I ask because it is unclear what you want Make to *do.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a target named `foo` to create `foo.elf` from `foo.o` which is built from `foo.c`, then you need an extra rule; in your example you create a rule `% : %.o` which builds `foo` from `foo.o`, but that's not what you want.  You want `foo.elf` to be built.

Also, you cannot use patterns INSIDE the recipe.  You have to use [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

So:

```
CC = gcc

% : %.elf ;

%.elf : %.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $^

%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $<
```

As Kerrek pointed out in comments above, you don't actually need the last pattern rule there since make already knows how to build a `.o` file from a `.c` file using built-in rules.

Now if you run `make foo` it will build `foo.elf`.

Comment: this example does not specifically handle #include dependencies, so if there was a foo.h (for instance) changing it would not force a re-compile/re-build.